# Dynamic dependencies in deep object graphs - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

I'm trying to modify some existing code to use Castle Windsor as an IoC container.

The application in question is document-oriented.  So it has an object graph that relies on data for specifying the data source that can't be known at registration time, and will change every time the object graph is resolved.  However, this dependency is a few layers into the object graph, so I can't just pass it as an argument to `container.Resolve()` since Windsor doesn't propagate inline dependencies.

The solution I've come up with instead is to use the typed factory facility to generate a factory which can resolve every dependency in the graph, and have `Document`'s constructor take an instance of this factory as well as a string specifying the data source.  The factory is specified at registration time, and the data source is specified at resolution time.  The constructor takes over from there, manually polling the factory to resolve is dependencies.  The result looks something like this:

```
public interface IDataSource { /* . . . */ }
public interface IWidgetRepository { /* . . . */ }
public interface IWhatsitRepository { /* . . . */ }

// Implementation generated by Windsor's typed factory facility
public interface IFactory
{
    IDataSource CreateDataSource(string path);
    IWidgetRepository CreateWidgetRepository(IDataSource dataSource);
    IWhatsitRepository CreateWhatsitRepository(IDataSource dataSource);

    void Release(IDataSource dataSource);
    void Release(IWidgetRepository widgetRepository);
    void Release(IWhatsitRepository whatsitRepository);
}

public class Document
{
    private readonly IDataSource _dataSource;
    private readonly IWidgetRepository _widgetRepository;
    private readonly IWhatsitRepository _whatsitRepository;

    public Document (IFactory factory, string dataSourcePath)
    {
        _dataSource = factory.CreateDataSource(dataSourcePath);
        _widgetRepository = factory.CreateWidgetRepository(_dataSource);
        _whatsitRepository = factory.CreateWhatsitRepository(_dataSource);
    }
}
```

This absolutely works, and does accomplish the goal of having Windsor take charge of dependency resolution.  Or at least, I can easily reconfigure the application by modifying the registration code.  At the moment I'm still making one call to `container.Resolve()` for every `Document` that gets created, but I believe that sin can easily be amended with a second Typed Factory.

However, it still feels wrong.  Windsor is in charge of newing up objects and (somewhat) managing their lifetimes, sure.  But it's not really injecting those dependencies into `Document`'s constructor; instead the constructor is pulling them out of the factory.  Worse, by passing the instance of `IDataSource` into the factory methods, it's taken charge of managing the object graph.  That seems like a huge subversion of the inversion to me.

So, what am I missing?

**EDIT**

To clarify, what I think I'm supposed to be shooting for is for `Document`'s constructor to look more like the below.

```
public Document (IDataSource dataSource, IWidgetRepository widgetRepository, IWhatsitRepository whatsitRepository)
{
    _dataSource = dataSource;
    _widgetRepository = widgetRepository;
    _whatsitRepository = whatsitRepository;
}
```

That way Windsor is in direct control of supplying all the objects' dependencies using constructor injection.  That's actually what the constructor signature looks like in the original code, but I was unable to get it to work with Windsor because `container.Resolve()` [doesn't propagate inline dependency parameters](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Passing-Arguments.ashx).  So I can't just do:

```
var document = container.Resolve<IDocument>(new { dataSourcePath = somePath });  // throws an exception
```

because Windsor doesn't pass `dataSourcePath` on to `DataSource`'s constructor, much less make sure that a `DataSource` instantiated with that path is passed on to the other constructors.

[An answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905496/516797) points out that this is by design - doing otherwise would introduce coupling.  This is a no-no, since one shouldn't mandate or assume that implementations of an interface have particular dependencies.  Sadly, that points out another way I think the code I came up with is wrong, since `Factory.CreateWidgetRepository()` and `Factory.CreateWhatsitRepository()` imply just that sort of assumption.

Comment: Does your `Document` need to maintain a reference to the `IDataSource _dataSource` or is that only used the once for creation of the the `IWidgetRepository` and `IWatsitRepository` in the constructor? EDIT: If you only need it for the construction, then I'd leverage constructor injection have the `Document` constructor take an `IWidgetRepository` and `IWhatsitRepository` rather than the `IFactory` altogether. Though, I don't have experience using Windsor, just basic constructor injection IoC frameworks (like Funq) so I'm not sure if that's applicable or not for Windsor.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I would very much prefer to have `Document`'s ctor take the repositories as parameters directly.  But given that Windsor doesn't propagate inline dependencies, I'm not really sure how to accomplish that.  In a nutshell, I guess that's really what this question's about.  (As the code is currently written, `Document` does use `_dataSource` directly for a few tasks.  Those bits could - and perhaps should - be refactored out, but I think that's really a separate issue from the one I'm running up against here.)

Answer (score 9):

I believe I've found the correct solution.  Apparently the available documentation wasn't quite explicit (verbose?) enough to bang the concept through my thick skull the first twelve times I read it, so I'll make an attempt to document it in more detail here for the sake of others who might be as helpless as I am. (I'll also let it sit a while before accepting in the hope that someone else might come along with any other/better suggestions.)

Long story short, Typed Factory Facility is the wrong tool for the job.

--

The trick is to use the DynamicParameters facility in the fluent registration API, which is (rather sparsely) documented [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/12/10/castle-windsor-new-feature-dynamic-parameters-from-registration-site.aspx) and in the last section [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-dependencies.ashx).

What DynamicParameters lets you do is directly modify the collection of inline parameters that was supplied when the container was asked to resolve a component.  This dictionary can then get passed on up the resolution pipeline, making it available to sub-dependencies.

`DynamicParameters` has three overloads, each taking a single delegate as its parameter.  These delegate types aren't explicitly documented, so for the sake of posterity here's what ReSharper (I'm too lazy to download the source.) tells me their declarations look like:

```
public delegate void DynamicParametersDelegate(IKernel kernel, IDictionary parameters);
public delegate ComponentReleasingDelegate DynamicParametersResolveDelegate(IKernel kernel, IDictionary parameters);
public delegate ComponentReleasingDelegate DynamicParametersWithContextResolveDelegate(IKernel kernel, CreationContext creationContext, IDictionary parameters);
```

`DynamicParametersDelegate` is for the most basic case, where you just need to supply parameters that won't be managed by the container.  That probably works for me, but in keeping with my tendency to find the complicated option first I ended up making a beeline for the second option, which is to supply a delegate which manually pulls dynamic parameters out of the container.  Since Windsor's managing the component's lifetime in that case, you need to make sure it's being released.  That's where `DynamicParametersResolveDelegate` comes in - it's just like the first one, except it also returns a `ComponentReleasingDelegate` (`public delegate void ComponentReleasingDelegate(IKernel kernel);`) which Windsor can use to release components at the appropriate time.

(The third, `DynamicParametersWithContextResolveDelegate`, is presumably for modifying the creation context.  I don't know enough about how Windsor works to actually understand what the preceding sentence means, so I'll have to leave it at that.)

That allows me replace the constructor from my example with the much better-looking:

```
public class Document
{
    private readonly IDataSource _dataSource;
    private readonly IWidgetRepository _widgetRepository;
    private readonly IWhatsitRepository _whatsitRepository;

    public Document (IDataSource dataSource, IWidgetRepository widgetRepository, IWhatsitRepository whatsitRepository)
    {
        _dataSource = dataSource;
        _widgetRepository = widgetRepository;
        _whatsitRepository = whatsitRepository;
    }
}
```

The factory is removed entirely.  Instead, the magic goes in the component registration code for `IDocument`:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IDocument>()
                   .ImplementedBy<Document>()
                   .DynamicParameters( 
                       (k, d) =>
                       {
                           // ask for an IDataSource, passing along any inline
                           // parameters that were supplied in the request for 
                           // an IDocument
                           var ds = k.Resolve<IDataSource>(d);

                           // Add it to the dictionary.  This makes it available
                           // for use when resolving other dependencies in the tree.
                           d.Add("DataSource", ds);

                           // Finally, pass back a delegate which can be used to release it
                           return (r) => r.ReleaseComponent(ds);
                       }));
```

So now I can ask for an `IDocument` with exactly the line of code I had been looking for:

```
var document = container.Resolve<IDocument>(new { dataSourcePath = somePath });
```

and the container starts by invoking that `DynamicParameters` delegate, which supplies the container with a `DataSource` for the supplied path.  From there the container's able to figure the rest out for itself so that the same instance of `DataSource` gets passed to the constructors for all three of the other objects in the dependency graph.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The problem I have with the above solution is that you will be calling :

```
var document = container.Resolve<IDocument>(new { dataSourcePath = somePath });
```

at each point where you need an IDocument. I think I should really be resolving all of my objects at a single point in the program and not using the container anywhere else. In other words, resolving a factory from the container once, and then using that factory at other points in the program. I think you were on the right track initially. Having said all that, I can't offer a better solution.