# Castle Windsor Abstract Factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to understand how to use `TypedFactoryFacility` to create an abstract factory, and I have it working at a basic level, however I don't fully understand how to scale it with runtime dependencies

Suppose I have a service that needs to be created at runtime:

```
public interface IRuntimeService {
  void DoThing();
}
```

with the following implementation

```
public class RuntimeService : IRuntimeService {
  public void DoThing() {
    // Do some work
  }
}
```

To create my `IRuntimeService`, I've created an abstract factory

```
public interface IRuntimeServiceFactory {
  IRuntimeService CreateService();
}
```

In my Castle installer, I'm using the `TypedFactoryFacility` to register my class and abstract factory.

```
public class TypeInstaller : IWindsorInstaller {

  public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
    container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    container.Register(Component.For<IRuntimeService>().ImplementedBy<RuntimeService>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IRuntimeServiceFactory>().AsFactory());
  }
```

Then in my class that will be using the service, I can use the factory to create new service instances at runtime.

```
var myService = m_ServiceFactory.CreateService();
```

---

**Everything above works perfectly**, however I'm running into a problem when my `RuntimeService` class needs to be injected with a dependency chain itself that include runtime parameters.

To expand the example above, suppose I have a new runtime dependency

```
public interface IRuntimeDependency {
  void DoWork();
}
```

implemented by a class that takes a runtime string value through the constructor

```
public class RuntimeDependency : IRuntimeDependency {

  private readonly string m_Param;

  public RuntimeDependency(string param) {
    m_Param = param;
  }

  public void DoWork() {
    // Do work involving the param
  }
}
```

And the previously defined service class now needs a reference to the dependency

```
public class RuntimeService : IRuntimeService {

  private readonly IRuntimeDependency m_Dep;

  public RuntimeService(IRuntimeDependency dep) {
    m_Dep = dep;
  }

  public void DoThing() {
    // Do some work involving the dependency
    m_Dep.DoWork();
  }
}
```

How do I now I create instances of my service using the `TypedFactoryFacility`?

I would expect do just be able to change my factory method to look like

```
IRuntimeService CreateService(string param);
```

but Windsor throws an error 'Could not resolve non-optional dependency for parameter 'param' type 'System.String'.

Windsor knows how to create an `IRuntimeDependency` if I give it a string, and it knows how to create a `IRuntimeService` if I give it the dependency, so why can't it directly create a `IRuntimeService` with the string param?

I can make it work by having two distinct factory methods

```
IRuntimeService CreateService(IRuntimeDependency dep);
IRuntimeDependency CreateDependency(string param);
```

and creating the dependency, manually myself

```
var dep = m_ServiceFactory.CreateDependency(param);
var myService = m_ServiceFactory.CreateService(dep );
```

**^^^This works**, but the whole point of using a container is so that it will take care of assembling new objects for me. This is a relatively simple example involving only one dependency, but it would easily grow out of control with a more complex object graph.

I could of course create my own factory implementations, but that also nullifies the benefit of using the `TypedFactoryFacility` which is supposed to create the abstract factory implementations for you. I have a hard time believing there's not an existing solution to this problem but the Windsor examples don't contain any chained run-time dependencies.

I don't think using a `FactoryComponentSelector` is the correct approach because there's only one possible path to create the `RuntimeService` instance. It should be able to auto-resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using [DynamicParameters](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md#supplying-dynamic-dependencies).

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRuntimeService>()
    .ImplementedBy<RuntimeService>()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    .DynamicParameters((k, d) => {
        d["dep"] = new RuntimeDependency((string)d["param"]);
    }));
```

Keep in mind that the dictionary keys have to match the parameter names in the `CreateService` method and `RuntimeService` constructor.

**Edit:** You should also make it [LifestyleTransient](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#transient) if you intend to create a new instance each time the factory method is called. (The default is singleton)

Answer (score 2):

In many or most cases, an object resolved by the container depends on implementations of other interfaces which are also resolved by the container. So as long as all of the interfaces have registered implementations, the container can resolve the entire dependency chain.

But in this case `RuntimeDependency` depends on a string, which isn't something the container can resolve.

```
public RuntimeDependency(string param) {
    m_Param = param;
}
```

In this case you can use the `DependsOn` method to explicitly provide a value to fulfill that dependency.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRuntimeDependency, RuntimeDependency>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("param","whatEverTheValueIs")));
```

That value can, of course, come from configuration or wherever else. I use this a lot with SQL connection strings.

Comment: Great, I think that gets me on the right track, but my parameter isn't a static value, it's a parameter that's passed in at runtime. How do I map the value passed into my factory to the `RuntimeDependency` constructor?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Whatever depends on the object can't pass it, so it must somehow be environmental. Maybe instead of a string you need another object that provides the string you need when you need it.

Comment: It's not environmental, it's a run-time parameter that's loaded from a file.

Comment: Then you would just define an interface for something that provides that value and create an implementation that reads it from the file. Register it 
with the container and inject that interface instead of a string. Or if it's not going to change while the application is running you could read the file during the container setup, get the value, and supply it as shown above.

Comment: My class that is requesting the service object is the one that is reading the file. And the file contents are able to be changed during runtime, so reading it at startup isn't an option. I don't see why I would need to create another class just to read the contents. I would still be in the same situation.

Comment: Think of it as something that your class depends on. It depends on something giving it this string parameter. At runtime that something is a class that reads from a file. But when unit testing it might just be an implementation that returns a hard-coded string for testing. So by doing this you make your class testable because it depends on an abstraction, not on the file system.

Comment: Ok I get where you're going. Let me try to refactor it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163441/discussion-between-dan-q-and-scott-hannen).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what I am asking for is not possible by design.

See this other SO answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905496/2029835